# Swagger UI not showing when Quarkus api deployed to Kubernetes

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I have deployed an api that is developed on Quarkus to Kubernetes by enabling swagger with the properties,

quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true
quarkus.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html

In local swagger comes up, but when deployed to Kubernetes, swagger UI doesnt show any api's, it shows below error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY4qZ.png)

any suggestions? on how to fix the issue?

Comment: your screenshot seem to be showing swagger correctly telling you /q/openapi is not something to find.  Are you openining just /swagger-ui.html ?

Comment: Yes, I am opening just /swagger-ui.html